# how to apply more than one indexing in a single statement

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic-tables

I am working on the dynamic table in which the javascript reads the tables then responds to it respectively to the tables' columns. I wished to use the *row* in the ***col*** statement for example `col = x[i].rows[row].cells.length`; instead.

```js
function add() {
  var x, y, z, i, j, row, col;
  x = document.querySelectorAll(".tab");

  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    y = x[i].insertRow();

    row = parseInt(x[i].rows.length);
    col = x[i].rows[1].cells.length; //should get the length of last row of the table
    for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      if (j == 0) {
        y.insertCell(j).innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox'>";
      } else {
        y.insertCell(j).innerHTML = row;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table border=1 class="tab">
  <tr>
    <td colspan=3>Table 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>c1</td>
    <td>c2</td>
  </tr>
</table><br>
<table border=1 class="tab">
  <tr>
    <td colspan=3>Table 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>c1</td>
    <td>c2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="add()">add</button>
```

Comment: do you mean to use `col = x[i].rows[row - 1].cells.length` to find the last row's columns length?

Comment: I've read this several times and it's not clear what you are trying to accomplish with `col` or what you need to do differently

Comment: kind of that @Ravikumar, but as you see, the code cannot execute the second indexing of [row - 1], I wished to use so

Comment: @charlietfl i wished to use x[i].rows[row].cells.length instead of x[i].rows[1].cells.length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate header `<tr>`s and body `<tr>`s with respective grouping tags. Then you can get `<tr>`s in body alone by using something like this `x[i].tBodies[0].rows.length`. Example has only one `tbody` tag thus directly reading 0 index.

```js
function add() {
  var x, y, z, i, j, row, col;
  x = document.querySelectorAll(".tab");

  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    y = x[i].insertRow();

    row = x[i].tBodies[0].rows.length;
    col = x[i].rows[row - 1].cells.length; //should get the length of last row of the table
    for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      if (j == 0) {
        y.insertCell(j).innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox'>";
      } else {
        y.insertCell(j).innerHTML = row;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table border=1 class="tab">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=3>Table 1</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>c2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button onclick="add()">add</button>
```